# iOS - viewDidLoad is being called BEFORE the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate?

Tags: ios, delegates, viewdidload

I have an application that is working as it was supposed to.

However, I put one breakpoint at the first line of my rootViewController's viewDidLoad method and another breakpoint in the first line of my delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

Surprisingly for me, the application entered in the viewDidLoad method, then went to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and then executed one more time the viewDidLoad method.

What is going on? I think that that behavior is totally wrong.

Thank you in advance!

#

Edited

Here goes my iPad's delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    UtilXML *utilXML = [[UtilXML alloc] init];
    [utilXML startXMLCommunication];
    int quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas = [utilXML quantidadaDeComicsBaixadas];

    main_iPad *mainiPad = [[main_iPad alloc] init];
    mainiPad.quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas = quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas;
    mainiPad.navigationItem.title = @"TitleFirstScreen";

    UIBarButtonItem *botaoSobre = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:mainiPad action:@selector(goToAboutView)];
    mainiPad.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = botaoSobre;

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainiPad];
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;


    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And here is my iPhone's delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

    UtilXML *utilXML = [[UtilXML alloc] init];
    [utilXML startXMLCommunication];
    int quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas = [utilXML quantidadaDeComicsBaixadas];

    main_iPhone *mainiPhone = [[main_iPhone alloc] init];
    mainiPhone.quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas = quantidadeDeComicsBaixadas;
    mainiPhone.navigationItem.title = @"TitleFirstScreen";

    UIBarButtonItem *botaoSobre = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:mainiPhone action:@selector(goToAboutView)];
    mainiPhone.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = botaoSobre;

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainiPhone];
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    navController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This strange behavior occurs in both devices.

Comment: Could you describe a little more what is going on inside your application delegate? Do you have multiple app delegates files? (ie iPhone/iPad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> You should use this method to initialize your application and prepare
>   it for running. It is called after your application has been launched
>   and **its main nib file has been loaded**. At the time this method is
>   called, your application is in the inactive state. At some point after
>   this method returns, a subsequent delegate method is called to move
>   your application to the active (foreground) state or the background
>   state.

So the view is lazily loaded for view controllers once the the `view` property or method is called. When this happens `viewDidLoad` is called so if your window `rootViewController` property is set to your root ViewController in the nib then this is expected behavior.

Comment: That was it! I removed the link in the rootViewController and it behaves as expected now (didFinishLaunchWithOptions is called before viewDidLoad). Thanks a million!!