# RestKit and fetchedResultsController performFetch is successful but fetchedObjects is empty

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have a UIViewController that is grabbing JSON data from a webservice and mapping it to an object (called a Post). In my viewDidLoad I am able to get this data from self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects. My issue is I am trying to do the same thing in a child view controller and the fetchedResultsController performFetch does not produce an error however the fetchedObjects is empty.

I pass the managedObjectContext like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PostsList"] == YES) {
        PostViewController *postsController = [segue destinationViewController];
        postsController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

In my storyboard I have done an embed segue with PostsList as the identifier. In my viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/flog/post" parameters:nil    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Fetched count %d",[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fail!");
    }]; 
}
```

My fetchedResultsController looks like:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSLog(@"The managedObjectContext %@", self.managedObjectContext);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSLog(@"fetchRequest appears ok %@", fetchRequest );

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Post"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSLog(@"The fetchedResultsController %@", aFetchedResultsController );
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

    NSLog(@"post fetched %@", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects );
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I have compared the behaviour to the parent controller and can not see any difference. Any help or debugging tips would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If the FRC is working (I assume it is, even if you are not showing the log output), the next thing you have to check is your display logic.

Make sure your table view datasource methods correctly display the fetched objects.

If you get 0 results in your FRC try setting the `cacheName` to `nil`. If there are still no records, examine the actual database. You will find the Simulator database at a location like

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Applications/
   <app-specific-sha>/Documents/
```

Then you can use the `sqlite3` command line tool to check for the `Post` entities.

Comment: I don't believe I will be able to display anything because the fetchedObjects count is 0 and I am using that as the return value in numberOfRowsInSection. If I change the return value to a random integer then it will display rows but with some default content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue stems from this similar issue [iOS - viewDidLoad is being called BEFORE the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030635/ios-viewdidload-is-being-called-before-the-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-deleg)

I originally was doing

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}
```

And I believe that this was being called before any JSON data was getting retrieved. I changed this to return _postCount and I set this at the end of my fetchedResultsController function. This is now working and in the console I can see the JSON getting pulled in before the self.fetchedResultsController performFetch.

In summary my issue was performFetch firing prior to JSON data coming in. I don't think my solution is the best one as it is just a workaround so if anyone can explain how to deal with/prevent this load order issue I will mark it as the correct answer. Cheers.