# iOS: NSUserDefault not loading fast enough in AppDelegate? Conditional fails intermittently

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I'm using NSUserDefault in AppDelegate to decide which VC to show to a user first after they load my app.

If user hasn't set a specific setting, they go to VC 1 where they set that.

If user has the setting, they go to VC 2 and on.

My problem is that sometimes I'm being sent to VC1 when I know I have the setting.

This leads me to believe that NSUserDefaults are not being fully loaded before my conditional checks for the value.

Could this be possible and if so is there a way to "block" the load process until the variable is fully loaded?

Here's the relevant code from AppDelegate that I'm using:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var window: UIWindow?

func updateNavBar(navBar: UINavigationBar) {
    navBar.barTintColor = UIColor(netHex:0x1d8696)
    navBar.tintColor = UIColor(netHex:0xAEFFDD)
    navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(netHex:0xAEFFDD),NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 16)!]

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    self.updateNavBar(UINavigationBar.appearance())



    if let team = self.prefs.stringForKey("team")
    {
        print("Team prefs found. (" + team + ") User sent to IVList")

        // show IVList VC

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // this assumes your storyboard is titled "Main.storyboard"
        let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController // inside "YOUR_VC_IDENTIFIER" substitute the Storyboard ID you created in step 2 for the view controller you want to open here. And substitute YourViewController with the name of your view controller, like, for example, ViewController2.
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()





        }else{

        // show editProfile VC
        print("No team prefs found. User sent to profile Edit")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // this assumes your storyboard is titled "Main.storyboard"
        let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editProfile") as! EditProfileViewController // inside "YOUR_VC_IDENTIFIER" substitute the Storyboard ID you created in step 2 for the view controller you want to open here. And substitute YourViewController with the name of your view controller, like, for example, ViewController2.
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }




    return true
}
```

I think it's a load timing thing because the issue is intermittent and inconsistent.  It happens about 20% of the time.

Comment: There is no "timing" issue. `NSUserDefaults` is nothing but a dictionary being loaded from a plist file. Your issue definitely does not have anything to do with `NSUserDefaults` being fully loaded (or not).

Comment: If that's the case then I suppose somewhere in my app there's code that's wiping out the user setting value without my knowledge.  That's the only other thing I can think of. Hm.

Comment: I've had experience in the past where I've made a mistake writing to the defaults (which goes undetected at compilation time and runtime) and then was scratching my head for ages as reading the value out had unexpected/unpredictable results. Writing a string as type int or vice versa etc. caused it to get its knickers in a twist.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had exactly this issue.

The simple answer is that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() in the appDelegate is only called AFTER the nib has been loaded for your initial view controller.

See the discussion at [iOS - viewDidLoad is being called BEFORE the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030635/ios-viewdidload-is-being-called-before-the-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-deleg)

Hope that helps!

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? This question is about the `if` statement inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: Sorry if this comes across as a bit cryptic. My thought process as follows: The question asked whether it is possible for NSUserDefaults not to be loaded before the view controller initialises. Given that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does indeed not complete until after the view controller initialises, then there is the possibility of a timing imbalance. This is exactly what happened to me a few weeks ago.

Comment: No, that's not what the question asked. It's about getting the proper value in the `if` statement in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It has nothing at all to do with view controllers being initialized.